# Push Notification not working in iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, push-notification, ios7.1, apns-sharp

**Apple Push notification** is not working specifically for my app only in **iPhone 4** device(iOS 7.1). Its working fine in other apps in iPhone 4 and it also works fine with 4s,5S,iPod touch. What might the issue?

Comment: You check in setting app? You get device token?

Comment: Yes I get device token! device Token is also registered on server.

Comment: Have you check notification section in setting app?

Comment: Yea. Notifications are enabled in device settings for the app. Internet connection also I have checked.